# Shortening code using functions

Tags: c++, function

I'm new to coding and i have a question about how to shorten code using function. My homework problem says that i need to take out the nested loops and shorten my previous code using functions and i need a little help jump starting. This code displays 100 random hex colors. I apologize for the messy code, still learning.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   srand(time(0));
      for(int j=0; j<100; j++){
         for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
          int digit = rand() % 16;
          char letter;
          if(digit > 9){
             letter = digit + 55;
             cout << letter;
          }
          else{
              cout << digit;
          }
      }
  cout << endl;
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about generating 100 random decimal integers and then printing them as hexadecimal (using `std::hex`)?

Comment: You should normally move code to functions if that part of the code is doing a specific work. In this case, you are not doing anything specific that can be reused.

Comment: Avoid magic number `55`, use `'A' - 10` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem statement suggests you modify the code as follows, but note that this does not reduce code size, just makes it more readable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void innerLoop(){
    char letter;
    int digit;
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++){
        digit = rand() % 16;
        if (digit > 9){
            letter = digit + 55;
            cout << letter;
        }
        else{
            cout << digit;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    for (int j = 0; j<100; j++){
        innerLoop();
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me in understanding functions!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to code frenzy' code change, there's an easier solution (although not necessarily educative) - generating 1000 **decimal** integers, then converting them to hexadecimal when printing using `std::hex`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    for(int j=0; j<100; j++){
        int number = rand() % 1000; // Or whatever your upper limit is.
        cout << hex << number << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely keep this in mind next time when using std::hex.

Answer (score 0):

The innermost loop is generating a random hexadecimal digit and printing that.
Let's break out the generation of digits into a function:

```
char random_digit() {
   int digit = rand() % 16;
   if (digit > 9) {
      return digit - 10 + 'A';
   }
   else {
      return digit;
   }
}

int main() {
   srand(time(0));
   for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
       for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
           cout << random_digit();
       }
       cout << endl;
   }
}
```

Now we have a loop that prints a number of random digits.
We can turn that into a function too.
Let's give it a parameter so we don't need to hard-code the length:

```
void print_number(int length) {
   for (int i= 0; i < length; i++) {
      cout << random_digit();
   }
   cout << endl;
}

// New main
int main() {
   srand(time(0));
   for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      print_number(6);
   }
   return 0;
}
```